# regular expression to check if string is valid XML

Tags: java, xml

I am looking java code to check if a string is valid XML.

Comment: Don't try it! Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-rege

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not possible to validate XML with regular expressions. XML is not a [regular language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language).

Use an XML parser to try to parse the string as XML or else validate the XML document against a schema, for example a [DTD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Definition) or [XSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_%28W3C%29) file.

Answer (score -3):

**you can check whether document or text  is well-formed, by using a parser.
i think this link will help you:**

**http://www.roseindia.net/xml/dom/DOMParserCheck.shtml**

**for string replace this line in the link:**

*InputSource is = new InputSource(xmlFile);*

**with**

ByteArrayInputStream stringStream=new ByteArrayInputStream("XML Text".getBytes());

InputSource is=new InputSource(stringStream);