# Regular Expression to check String is valid XHTML or not

Tags: java, xhtml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [regular expression to check if string is valid XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564989/regular-expression-to-check-if-string-is-valid-xml)

I am looking Regular Expression to check String is Valid XHTML or not

example

```
<h2>Legal HTML Entity References</h2><table align="center" border="0" ><tr></tr></table>
```

Comment: You really need read something about Chomsky language hierarchy and formal grammars. You can check only regular language with regular expression and the XHTML is not regular language.


[1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar#The_Chomsky_hierarchy

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like a bad idea: The language of valid XHTML strings is *not regular*.

Use an HTML parsing library instead. A few examples:

- [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/)
- [TagSoup](http://mercury.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/)
- [HTMLParser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/)

---

**Related question:**

- [When should I not use regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553722/when-should-i-not-use-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 1):

Regex is exactly the wrong tool to use.

> HTML is not a regular language and hence cannot be parsed by regular expressions.

See Jeff's post on the subject here:
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Since you've tagged this post Java, you should look at using one of the myriad of HTML parsing libraries available.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here why parsing HTML using regular expressions won't work reliably: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

XHTML is just another flavor/superset of HTML, so you're better of using a real validator, like JTidy etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check it with a parser. Don't do it the [Cthulhu Way](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html).

Here you can find a strating point and some examples on how to do it: [The Java XML Validation API](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-javaxmlvalidapi/index.html)